# Effect of Synergic Bonding on Bond Lengths in Metal Carbonyls

Tags: coordination-compounds

Consider the metal carbonyl, pentacarbonyl iron(0). There exists synergic bonding between the central metal atom, iron and the neutral carbonyl ligands. This strengthens the metal-ligand bond but because electron density from the filled orbitals of the Iron atom is pushed into the anti bonding orbital of the $\ce{C-O}$ bond, it is weakened thereby increasing bond length. My question was to what extent does the $\ce{C-O}$ bond length increase. Also, is this increase uniform? The reason for my doubt was, the compound has a trigonal bipyramidal type geometry. So the axial metal-ligand bonds are weaker than the equatorial ones. I felt that synergic bonding would not take place to the same extents in the axial and equatorial case - the synergic bonding would be stronger in the equatorial case and weaker in the axial case. Is that so?